# PyQT example(s) not running second time

Tags: python, pyqt4, spyder

I'm trying to write a simple GUI in Python 2.7 (anaconda, iPyhon using Spyder). Starting with a simple example that displays a window with a quit button.
The [example is from here.](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/firstprograms/)

this is the code I'm running in the Spyder IDE:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
ZetCode PyQt4 tutorial 

This program creates a quit
button. When we press the button,
the application terminates. 

author: Jan Bodnar
website: zetcode.com 
last edited: October 2011
"""

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):               

        qbtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit', self)
        qbtn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())
        qbtn.move(50, 50)       

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Quit button')    
        self.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It runs the first time, but when I run it again the Python crashes. Very hard to develop like this.. :-) Starting a new ipython console will allow me to run once again.
I already changed sys.exit(app.exec_()) to app.exec_() since I don't want to close the iPython kernel, but that makes no difference.
Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: For pyqt5, the doc says to [avoid a main() method](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html#object-destruction-on-exit), because the interpreter could crash.

Comment: This blog post: [Making PyQt4, PySide and IPython work together](http://cyrille.rossant.net/making-pyqt4-pyside-and-ipython-work-together/) could also be helpful. One other thing to consider is: do you really need IPython ? Why not just do `python myCode.py` ?